# My code for merge sort in C++ using dynamic arrays returning garbage values

Tags: sorting, merge, garbage

Please tell me why this code is giving garbage values
Compiles well, implemented this based on the Cormen algorithm for mergesorting
Basically taking given numbers in a dynamic array. two void functions are taken.One is to merge the two sub arrays via merge sort and the other to recursively split the array to sub arrays

```
#include<iostream> 
using namespace std;
void merge(int *A,int p, int q, int r)// a  function to merge two //sub arrays
{
     int n1= q-p+1;
     int n2=r-q;
     int L[n1];
     int R[n2];
     for (int i=0;i<n1;i++)
     {
         L[i]=A[p+i];
     }
         int m=1;
     for(int j=0; j<n2 ;j++)
     {
         R[j]=A[q+m];
         m=m+1;
     }
     int i=0;
     int j=0;
     for(int k=0;k<r;k++)
     {
             if (L[i]<=R[j])
             {
            A[k]=L[i];
             i=i+1;
             }

             else
             {
             A[k]=R[j];
              j=j+1;
              }
 }


        }

void mergesort(int *A,int p,int r)// dividng the sequence to sub arrays
{

     if (p<r)     
         {
                  int q;
                  q=(p+r)/2;
                  mergesort(A,p,q);
                  mergesort(A,(q+1),r);
                  merge(A,p,q,r);

                  }

                   }
int main()
{
   int n;
    cout<<"Enter the number of numbers to be sorted by merge sort"<<endl;
    cin>>n;
    int* a=NULL;
    a=new int[n];
    int temp;

    cout<<"Enter the numbers"<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
            cin>>temp;
            *(a+i)=temp;// inputting the given numbers into a dynamic array
            }

    cout<<"The given numbers are:"<<endl;
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
    cout<<*(a+j)<<" ";

      mergesort(a,0,n-1);

  cout<<"The merged sorted numbers are:"<<endl;
    for(int s=0;s<n;s++)
        cout<<*(a+s)<<" "; 

        delete [] a;
     system("pause"); 
          return 0;
          }
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'garbage values'? Does the output consist out of the values of the input, but is not sorted properly?

Comment: Debugging tip: try testing your `merge` routine on its own to see if it works.

Comment: Codor . the code is returning random values .. values that are not in the given input array

Answer (score 0):

You are getting your intervals wrong pretty much everywhere in your code. For example:

- Based on your usage in `main`, `mergesort` is supposed to sort the sublist of indices `[0,n-1]`.

With this meaning, your recursion in `mergesort` says in order to sort the indices `[p,r-1]`, you should first sort `[p,q-1]` then sort `[q+1,r-1]`: you completely ignore index `q`.

Similarly, `merge` is confused: once you fix the typo when coping into `L` (`A[i]` should be `A[p+i]`), it takes `[p,q]` as one list, and `[q,r]` as the other list: note you copy entry `q` twice, and you also copy `r` when you probably shouldn't be.

---

To fix your code, you need to straighten out exactly what intervals everything is supposed to be working on. This isn't a *hard* problem, you just have to bring yourself to write down *explicitly* *exactly* what all of your functions and loops and stuff are supposed to be doing.

The typical convention these days is half-open intervals: you should generally think of taking indices `[p,q)` from a list. (`[p,q)` is the same as `[p,q-1]`) Here are several examples of why this is preferred:

- The number of entries of `[p,r)` is simply `r-p`
- A `for` loop iterating through `[p,r)` is the usual `for(i=p; i<r; ++i)` (not `<=`)
- Splitting the interval `[p,r)` into parts gives you intervals `[p,q)` and `[q,r)` -- there is no worry about remembering to add `1` in places.

e.g. `merge` would normally be designed to take the first list comes from indices `[p,q)` and the second list from indices `[q,r)`.

Comment: fixed the typo,L[i}=A[p+i], also I intend to do something like [p,q],(q,R], implemented with the help of another variable called m,r is intended to be taken into account, changed the functional call to mergesort(a,0,n-1)  also, still getting random values .,